# why is a leap year returning a none also?

Tags: python-3.x

to check if the provided is a leap year or not and then return the ans in terms of true or false using functions

```
enter code here
    def leapcount(inp):
if inp%4==0 or inp%400==0:
    print('True')
elif inp%100==0:
    print('False')
else:
    return ('False')
```

inpp=int(input('Enter the year to check for leap year format:'))
print(leapcount(inpp))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are printing the result of the function- instead of printing the words true and false you can return the boolean values of `True` and `False` and then print that result to get what you want

```
def leapcount(inp):
  if inp%4==0 or inp%400==0:
    return True;
  elif inp%100==0:
    return False
  else:
    return False

inpp=int(input('Enter the year to check for leap year format:'))

print(leapcount(inpp)) #Prints 'True' or 'False' depending on Input Value
```

Originally you were just printing in your function and not returning. In python- functions without return values will return None which is what you were seeing in the output.

Comment: Using `return` is correct but conditions are wrong, though it is OP's problem not yours :)

Answer (score 0):

Just want to bring your attention - your code is wrong. `inp%100==0` verification has higher priority than `inp%4==0` so must be verified earlier.

You should verify `inp%400==0`, then `inp%100==0`, then `inp%4==0`